# GET inner Div textvalue with same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I did a form on which you can click a + button and add clones... The div inside has 3 elements - a span, a textbox and the button.

I clone like this:

```
        <script>
        var actorcount = 1;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document.getElementById("btexp1")).click(function(){
              var $div = $('div[id^="actordiv"]:last');
              var id= Number( $div[0].id.match(/\d+/g) ) + 1;
              var $clones=$div.clone().attr('id', 'actordiv'+id);
              $div.after($clone);
              actorcount++;
                });
            });
    </script>
```

This clones the div and gives the id = "actordiv"+counter;

The div HTML is like this:

```
            <div id="actordiv" style=" padding-left: 5px">
            <span class="add-on"><strong>Actor</strong></span>
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="actor" style="height:30px">
            <span class="btn" id="btexp1">+</span>
        </div>
```

The problem is the textbox inside all the divs created have the same id="actor";

Now I want to access the textbox with the id="actor" inside all the divs the user made which will have the ids="actordiv1" 2 3 etc... how can I access this with PHP?

Or if better change the textbox id="actor" ids...

Comment: Add increments to the "actor" ID as well, as ID's must be unique.

Comment: How do i access it? is it that easy?

Comment: `$('[id^="actor"]')` selects all elements that starts with "actor" etc ?

Comment: got it... $('[id="actor"]').attr('id','actor'+id); The new one gets actor and the last one is actor+count..